# I am attempting to use Spring Security Core on a grails project, getting the following error

Tags: grails, spring-security

I am running **Grails 3.3.8** and **spring-security-core:3.2.3** and unable to run/startup my application. I only have on additional bean defined in the resources.groovy and not much custom within the application.

Here is the stacktrace that I am getting, what could be causing this?

```
Caused by: grails.plugins.exceptions.PluginException: Failed to initialize class [grails.plugin.springsecurity.LoginController] from plugin [springSecurityCore] : org/grails/compiler/web/converters/RenderConverterTrait
        at org.grails.plugins.BinaryGrailsPlugin.initializeProvidedArtefacts(BinaryGrailsPlugin.java:175)
        at org.grails.plugins.BinaryGrailsPlugin.<init>(BinaryGrailsPlugin.java:104)
        at grails.plugins.DefaultGrailsPluginManager.createBinaryGrailsPlugin(DefaultGrailsPluginManager.java:375)
        at grails.plugins.DefaultGrailsPluginManager.findCorePlugins(DefaultGrailsPluginManager.java:362)
        at grails.plugins.DefaultGrailsPluginManager.attemptLoadPlugins(DefaultGrailsPluginManager.java:314)
        at grails.plugins.DefaultGrailsPluginManager.loadPlugins(DefaultGrailsPluginManager.java:224)
        at grails.boot.config.GrailsApplicationPostProcessor.initializeGrailsApplication(GrailsApplicationPostProcessor.groovy:89)
        at grails.boot.config.GrailsApplicationPostProcessor.setApplicationContext(GrailsApplicationPostProcessor.groovy:225)
        at grails.boot.config.GrailsApplicationPostProcessor.<init>(GrailsApplicationPostProcessor.groovy:77)
        at grails.boot.config.GrailsAutoConfiguration.grailsApplicationPostProcessor(GrailsAutoConfiguration.groovy:68)
        at greenfield.Application.grailsApplicationPostProcessor(Application.groovy)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrMethodInvoke(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1426)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:162)
        ... 24 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/grails/compiler/web/converters/RenderConverterTrait
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:763)
        at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:467)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:73)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:368)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:362)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:361)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:335)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:411)
        at groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader.loadClass(GroovyClassLoader.java:677)
        at groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader.loadClass(GroovyClassLoader.java:787)
        at groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader.loadClass(GroovyClassLoader.java:775)
        at org.grails.plugins.BinaryGrailsPlugin.initializeProvidedArtefacts(BinaryGrailsPlugin.java:173)
        ... 40 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.grails.compiler.web.converters.RenderConverterTrait
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:335)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
        ... 56 common frames omitted
```

Comment: Could you please show how did you add the spring-security dependency to your build.gradle?

Comment: `compile 'org.grails.plugins:spring-security-core:3.2.3'`

Comment: the class `RenderConverterTrait` is located in `converters-3.3.1.jar` and is independent of SpringSec. Something must be messed up with your config. Try cleaning it up